# WooCommerce Button to Clear Cart, Add One Item and go to Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I need a button on a unique landing page which does this:

1. clears the cart
2. adds a specific Item to the cart
3. go directly to checkout
4. (disable or hide menue-bar in checkout) <-I tried this with JavaScript but failed

I got a button which calls the link: `https://www.snoooze.co/?add-to-cart= 12374`

And then this snippet in my "functions.php"

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'woo_redirect_to_checkout');
function woo_redirect_to_checkout() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $checkout_url; }
```

The problem is that if I add the item in my function with `add_to_Cart()` it does this every time I want to add it manually in the shop, not just if I click on the button on the landing page.

I see that I have to assign the function to the button in some way, so doesn't get called on other sites, but how?

Any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a custom button embedded in an form. So here is a simple shortcode that you can use in a content editor or in php:

```
// Shortcode: Special button "add-to-cart" with form
function special_button() {
    return '<form method="post" action="">
        <button type="submit" class="button" name="add_to_cart_special">Special add to cart</button>
    </form>';
}
add_shortcode( 'special_button', 'special_button' );

// Usage: [special_button] 
// or for php: echo do_shortcode("[special_button]");
```

And this custom hooked function that will be triggered when you press that custom button. It will:

- empty cart,
- add product 12374 to cart
- redirect to checkout
- display a custom notice in checkout page (optionally)

The code:

```
// Special add to cart (empty cart before and redirect to checkout)
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'special_add_to_cart' );
function special_add_to_cart() {
    if ( isset($_POST['add_to_cart_special']) ){
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 12374 );
        wc_add_notice( __('this product X has been added to cart'), 'notice' );
        wp_redirect( wc_get_checkout_url() );
        exit();
    }
}
```

*ALL Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

> But to disable or hide your "menu bar" in checkout, I really don't know… This should be another new question with more details…

Comment: I'm very sorry for my late response!
It worked perfectly - thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired functionality of clearing the cart and redirecting the user to the checkout page with the new product added, you can modify the **function.php** code as follows:

```
function clear_cart_and_redirect_to_checkout() {
if (class_exists('woocommerce') && isset($_GET['add-to-cart'])) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

    $product_id = sanitize_text_field($_GET['add-to-cart']);
    $quantity = 1; // You can adjust the quantity if needed

    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity);

    // Redirect to the checkout page
    wp_redirect(wc_get_checkout_url());
    exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'clear_cart_and_redirect_to_checkout');
```

After making the changes, Just change the link simply with: **/checkout/?add-to-cart=XXXX**.